# MySQL performance for aggregate functions -- 80Million records

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I am currently stuck in improving the performance of MySQL query. It takes 30 seconds to execute and we don't want users waiting that long for the backend response.

My Query:

```
select count(case_id), sum(net_value), sum(total_time_spent), events from event_log group by events order by count(case_id) desc
```

Indexes:

```
Created a composite index on events,case_id, net_value, total_time_spent.
```

Time taken:`30 seconds`

Number of records in event_log table:`80 Million`

Table structure:

`Create table event_log( case_id varchar(100) primary key, events varchar(200), creation_date timestamp, total_time_spent bigint)`

Composite Unique key: `case_id, events, creation_date.`

Infrastructure: 
AWS RDS instance type : `r5d.2xlarge ( 8CPUs, 64GB RAM )`

Tried partitioning the data on the basis of key case_id but could see no improvement.
Tried upgrading the server size but no improvement there as well.

If you can give us some hints, or something that we can try that would be really helpful.

Comment: You're scanning the whole 80M table on every query, which is bound to take a long time. I suggest running the query every 5 minutes in a backend thread, and storing the result in a cache. Then user requests just read the most recent cached result very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your response Bill!
However, this is the initial dashboard query but there are certain dimensions that the user can apply as filters
So the response is going to be dynamic from user to user.
Even if we cache the initial query data, the filter queries are still going to take time.

Are we saying caching is the only way and the performance cannot be improved further?

Comment: Optimizing aggregates over large data sets is hard, and allowing users to specify their own custom filters makes it even harder. There's not much you can do to avoid table-scans. There are column-oriented datastores like ClickHouse that specialize in this type of query. See https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/02/03/clickhouse-and-mysql-better-together/

Comment: Another alternative is LeapDB, which is a column-oriented datastore implemented as a MySQL storage engine. See https://www.leapdb.com/

Comment: Okay, will check out LeapDB. But as a quick fix, do you think increasing the DB RAM or maybe increasing buffer pool size will help ( current buffer pool size is 20GB and overall data is 21GB )?
Or do you feel 30 seconds is the best time that we are already getting?

Comment: I can't predict that. I don't know if the size of your log table will fit in RAM, I don't know what other tables and queries are running, that also need to use RAM, and so on. I've seen cases where the extra RAM made no difference, or did make the query an order of magnitude faster. You'll have to test it in your environment to know.

Answer (score 0):

Build and maintain a [*Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) of events by day (or week) and subtotals of the counts and sums you need.

Then run the query against the summary table, summing up the sums, etc.

That may run 10 times as fast.

If practical, normalize case_id and/or events; that may shrink the table size by a significant amount.  Consider using a smaller datatype for the `total_time_spent`; `BIGINT` consumes 8 bytes.

With a summary table, few, if any, indexes are needed; the summary table is likely to have indexes.  I would try to have the `PRIMARY KEY` start with `events`.

Be aware that `COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being `NOT NULL`.   If this is not necessary, then simply do `COUNT(*)`.